# Visual Studio 2k8: specifying custom properties

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'd like to use custom build properties to drive the build process. Is it possible to specify them using Visual Studio user interface? I'd like to avoid editing the msbuild file every time I need to change the property.

Maybe VS2010 has support for that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that using the Visual Studio itself.
However, there are some extenal applications to do that, for example: MSBuild Sidekick or MSBuild Explorer.

Comment: Thank you for providing alternatives.

Comment: You are correct there is no UI support for custom properties and items.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the user interface.

But if you unload the project (right click on project node in Solution Explorer) then you can open the project file to directly edit the XML (another right click).

Comment: That's what I'd like to avoid. Not everybody in our team has knowledge about MS Build.

Comment: MSBuild is pretty easy (especially for easy stuff), if members of the dev team are struggling with it I would worry about their ability to write production code (unfortunately).

Comment: Sometimes people join teams not because they can program well, but because they are field specialists.